# makecell causes wrong alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cellspace

I got the following simple table, for which I am using `makecell` for nice spacing. But the alignment of multicolumn in the first row is somehow wrong. It should be left aligned, but is centered. For the following rows, it works again. Any hints why this is the case? I am also using  siunitx, because I do not know if the problem comes from there (even though it might not make too much sense here as there is only one row)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{12pt}\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
      lSSlSSS
  }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{This text should be left aligned} \\
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 \\
  \hline
  0.123 & 0.123  & 0.123  & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the question you mention the `cellspace` package while the code atually uses `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package instead. Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis sorry, fixed. I always confuse the two packages for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to get rid of the undesired center alignment while still using `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package, here is an alternative solution using `cellspace` instead. (In the second table, I have also added `\sisetup` in order to assign an appropriate `table-format` option to the `S` type columns. I have also enclosed all non-numberic content in `S` type columns in a set of `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{12pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
      0l S S 0l S S S
  }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{0l}{This text should be left aligned} \\
    Column 1 & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & Column 4 & {Column 5} & {Column 6} & {Column 7} \\
  \hline
  0.123 & 0.123  & 0.123  & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\begin{tabular}{
      0l S S 0l S S S
  }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{0l}{This text should be left aligned} \\
    Column 1 & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & Column 4 & {Column 5} & {Column 6} & {Column 7} \\
  \hline
  0.123 & 0.123  & 0.123  & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround with `\rlap` in a `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{12pt}\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
      lSSlSSS
  }
  \hline
  \makecell[l]{\rlap{This text should be left aligned}} \\
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 \\
  \hline
  0.123 & 0.123  & 0.123  & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a good workaround!